# How to get user-agent, referrer from nginx error log

Tags: nginx

guys,

I see a lot of errors like the following in my nginx's `error.log`:

```
2016/01/06 15:57:41 [error] 9054#0: *381280040 open() "/mypath/current/public/images/default_avatar.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 222.83.227.19, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET //images/default_avatar.png HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mydomain.com"
```

But I could not find a place where I've wrongly referred to the image. Is there a way that I could print the `user-agent` and `referrer` of this request, so that I could find out where I've done wrong?

Best Regards.
Larry

Answer (score 1):

You you might look for where your `log_format` is defined then add `"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"`.

Comment: I don't think I could customized log format of nginx's error.log. It's in the error.log not access.log.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`access_log`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log) to log requests with [HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) 4xx (Client errors) and 5xx (Server errors) except 499 which is nginx Status code for client connection close.

```
#access_log      off;
map $status $loggable {
    ~^[45]  1;
    499     0; # client closed connection
    default 0;
}
access_log /var/log/nginx/error.log combined if=$loggable;
```